# $ sh < foo > bar this statement is the question

Tags: scripting

What this is the following command doing? I'm new, and still learning.

```
$ sh < foo > bar
```

How to interpret it step by step so that I can get clear understanding more question like this.

Comment: What is what indicating?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. This command has three parts:

```
sh
```

`sh` is the name of the program to be run, in this case, it's the `sh`.

```
< foo
```

`<` simbol says that the word following it is the name of a file and commands the shell(shell which executes the command, it has nothing to do with sh, the program being called, which happens to be a shell) to join the standard input of the program to the contents of file whose name follows the symbol, `foo` in this case.

```
> bar
```

`>` symbol commands the shell to join the standard output of the program being executed to the file `bar`.

These redirection paths are setup before the execution of the program begins.

So the whole command, `sh < foo > bar`, when run on a shell. makes the program `sh` read commands from file `foo` and store it's output in the file `bar`. It's an error if the file `foo` doesn't exist. The behavior of the shell depending on whether file `bar` exists or not is determined by the `noclobber` option of the shell you use.

Answer (score 0):

In general,

```
$ utility <input >output
```

will cause `utility` to be executed with its *standard input stream* connected to the file `input` and its *standard output stream* connected to the file `output`.

The `$` at the start of the line is the shell prompt (you will not type this).

In the case of `sh`, which is a shell command interpreter, this will cause `sh` to read and execute the shell commands from the input file (`foo` in your case) and write any output to the output file (`bar` in your case).  Diagnostic messages (errors and warnings) will still be displayed on the terminal since these are usually written to the *standard error stream*, which the command line that you mentioned does not redirect anywhere in particular.

The command that you mentioned has more or less the same effect as

```
$ sh foo >bar
```

since `sh` is able to read from the file mentioned on its command line and will only read from the standard input stream if no file is mentioned.

Comment: Note that those redirections (the new resources now attached to stdin and stdout) are inherited by all the commands started by that `sh`. That's a big difference between `sh < foo` and `sh foo`: for the commands in that `foo` script, stdin will be the `foo` file in the `sh < foo` case.